# Do clear transparent pieces suffer from a yellow tinge over time?

Tags: piece-information, colour, plastics

Any idea if clear 1×1 round plates suffer from color differences? I recently got a bag of them and they appear to have a yellow tinge.

Comment: Yes, this has been a known issue. I'm not going to post this as an answer, as I can't remember where I read about it, and thus can't include references, but it has been discussed in a number of LEGO fan forums.

Comment: One forum note that I found: https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/52672-transparent-part-yellowing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the clear pieces depend on the piece. Some of the thinner ones do yellow, but I have 2x4 Clear bricks that are not yellowed. I think it depends on the thickness of the ABS that was used.